# Can I show another folder beside the General folder inside MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

We have a SharePoint team site and inside MS Teams we can view the General folder as follow:-

[image]

Now inside the sharepoint site I added a new folder named test beside the General folder, as follow:-

[image]

but this new folder did not appear inside Ms Team.. so is there a way to automatically show any folder added to the root of the document library inside MS Teams? If not then can i do it manually?
Thanks

Comment: You can add document library as a separate tab on Teams. that way you can see all folders inside document library.

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you advice more on this please?>

Comment: To add document library as a tab in Teams, check this: [Add a SharePoint page, list, or document library as a tab in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/add-a-sharepoint-page-list-or-document-library-as-a-tab-in-teams-131edef1-455f-4c67-a8ce-efa2ebf25f0b). let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap this will add the Document library under the General tab is this correct? while i need the folder to be shown under Software development inside MS Teams

Comment: There is no tabs on the Team itself only on the channel, of which you only have General currently. @GaneshSanap is correct, you can either add the library as a separate tab on a channel or alternatively you can just create another channel which will have it's own folder (shown as files on that channel).

Comment: @CallumCrowley can you advice more on this please?

Comment: @GaneshSanap now i find a workaround, i can create  a new channel inside MS Teams named "test" and this channel will get mapped automatically to the test folder is this fine?

Comment: @CallumCrowley Now i find a workaround, i can create a new channel inside MS Teams named "test" and this channel will get mapped automatically to the test folder is this fine?

Comment: Yes, but that will create a new channel and not showing all files in "General" channel automatically. if you are OK with creating new channel then it's fine.

Comment: @GaneshSanap the user is asking to show all the folders under the Software Development site tile. so i can not find any other way rather than creating new channels..am i right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automatically show any folder added to Shared Documents libray inside MS Teams.

As a workaround, we could add a new Channel in Microsoft Teams, than the mapped folder will show in SharePoint Shared Documents libray.

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sharepoint-onedrive-interact

Comment: but since in my case i already have the folders created,, so if i add a channel with the same name as the folder then the channel will get mapped to the folder... is this correct?

Comment: No, this will occur error, we suggest you add channel with different name or delete existing folder in document library, then add channel with previous name.

Comment: no this will not raise any errors i tired it..

Comment: So will the old folder be overwrite in SharePoint Shared Documents or create a new folder?